# Can't import opvn file & fan Issue

Tags: vpn, fedora, fan

I am using Fedora 37 and it was succesful installation no errors at all but all of the sudden.

I hear my laptop making weird fan noises like it goes so fast then it return like normal. I don't see any high temprature on the GPU. I've cleaned the laptop but that didn't solve the problem.

I noticed that it only happens when i am using power save mode.

---

Also, I am trying to import this file from tunnelbear VPN:

```
client
dev tun0
proto udp
nobind
ns-cert-type server
persist-key
persist-tun
reneg-sec 0
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4
redirect-gateway
verb 5
auth-user-pass
ca CACertificate.crt
cert UserCertificate.crt
remote ar.lazerpenguin.com 443
cipher AES-256-GCM
auth SHA256
keysize 256
```

And when I try to import it the error says:

```
The file could not be read or does not contain recognized VPN connection information

Error: Key file contains line "client" which is not a key-value pair, group, or comment.
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: One question per post please, so that we can give you a single correct answer. You can make more than one post at a time